# implementing logout in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, scripting, logout

I am working on a small web application. Login page will set user object as a session attribute. Particular components will be served to the user if the variable is not null. I'd also like (need) to add an option to log out. This is what comes to my head:
an anchor to a page that invalidates the session, like

```
<% session.invalidate(); %>
You were logged out.
```

but this means a use of scripting. Similarly, I could create a custom tag that does the same, but if would just hide the scripting from jsps. Another idea is to add a form and put the session invalidation in a servlet - but I would end up in multiple forms in one page, which doesn't sound good either. The last thing that comes to my head is to a jvascript. Is there another solution you'd suggest?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a link which targets to a servlet and invalidate your session in there. You do not need any form, just a smiple link will be enough. Please let me know if I understand it correct!

Comment: however, why don't you use standard FORM-based auth + `request.logout()` instead of reinveinting the wheel?

Comment: @Michele Mariotti - I know that the mechanism exists. Is it being used frequently?

Comment: @Łukasz yes, it is simple, standard and portable across containers. and you can take advantage of pre-defined realms features like `LockOutRealm`, `JndiRealm`, ...

Comment: It would be better to redirect than print a message here <% session.invalidate(); response.sendRedirect("loginform"); return; %> that way this JSP can be nothing but these two lines of code and any HTML and formatting can be in the servlet or whatever you redirect to. That will keep things clean and make you feel better about using a scriptlet.